# Spell check and get the suggested list in the next cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing spell check in a range by using the below code..

```
Sub SpellCheck()

Application.SpellingOptions.DictLang = 1033

Dim cel As Range, CellLen As Long, CurChr As Long, TheString As String
Dim a As Integer

For Each cel In Range("Spell[description]")

'splitting paragraph into words

    For CurChr = 1 To Len(cel.Value)
        If Asc(Mid(cel.Value, CurChr, 1)) = 32 Then
            If InStr(CurChr + 1, cel.Value, " ") = 0 Then
                TheString = Mid(cel.Value, CurChr + 1, Len(cel.Value) - CurChr)
            Else
                TheString = Mid(cel.Value, CurChr + 1, InStr(CurChr + 1, cel.Value, " ") - CurChr)
            End If
            'checking spell as per words
            If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=TheString) Then

                cel.Characters(CurChr + 1, Len(TheString)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                'updating the error words in the next sheet
                Sheets(2).Activate
                a = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Cells(a + 1, 1).Value = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
                Cells(a + 1, 2).Value = TheString
            Else
                cel.Characters(CurChr + 1, Len(TheString)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End If
            TheString = ""
        End If
    Next CurChr

Next cel

End Sub
```

It will highlight the error words in red and update them along with its ID and error word in sheet2. However i need to update the suggested values provided for the error by excel in the next cell (after error words in sheet2).

I'm completely new to this spell check in VBA, can anyone help me out..!

Comment: I don't *think* Excel/VBA provides programmatic access to the spelling suggestions. You might consider a hack like creating using automation on a  MS Word object and using its autocorrect.

Comment: Oh thanks for the update :)

Comment: One small question is it possible to change the spell error to change it to the correct word without prompting in spell check?